# Is there a really good open source video player in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

That has all the basic functionality like play, pause, stop, forward, rewind, and volume controls?

Comment: you must build your own player but the functions are there.. but if there is free.. then maybe you can google it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the Flex 4 SDK, the new spark VideoPlayer has everything out of the box.

Comment: +1.  This new feature alone was enough to push us to the Flex 4 SDK, despite it being in beta.  The alternative required using Flash Professional...ick.

Answer (score 2):

Here some sample player with code

[Website](http://tarasnovak.com/blog/2009/01/16/simple-flex-video-player/)

[Source Code](http://www.tarasnovak.com/lab/SimpleVideoPlayer/srcview/index.html)

[Download Source Code](http://www.tarasnovak.com/lab/SimpleVideoPlayer/srcview/SimpleVideoPlayer.zip)

Hope this helps.

Comment: nice, thanks. I am mainly looking if there is one that people really like it that is clean and easy to extend. This one looks pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [**Open Source Media Framework**](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/about.html)

> This site is intended to facilitate the development and sharing of open standards and best practices for video player applications built on the Adobe® Flash® Platform.

Answer (score 1):

Not opensource (AFAIK), but it has everything you could ever wish for.

[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)

Comment: It says on the site that it is gpl'd

Answer (score 0):

JW Video Player:  http://www.longtailvideo.com/

http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.0

I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opensouce player for Flash, Flex, Silverlight, iphone. Just the download pack for the source codes and examples.[Open Video Player](http://openvideoplayer.sourceforge.net/)

I hope my anwser was helpfull

DJ